# Keeping certain element always at the start of a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
d = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C':3}
```

I need the Key 'A' to always be first in this dict because certain processes throughout the program depend on it being there.

While performing operations on this dictionary it will get unordered.

What is the easiest to ensure 'A' remains the first key throughout this program no matter operations I perform on it?

Comment: Use an OrderedDict instead, and set `a` as the first key

Answer (score -1):

Make it an `OrderedDict` instead of a plain dictionary, add `A` as the first key before you do anything else, and never delete that key.

Answer (score -1):

Dictionary objects don't guarantee to keep the keys and values in the order they were inserted, but Python 3.1 has a [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) class that can be used for this purpose.

Comment: It does from 3.6 (CPython) and 3.7  (all Pythons)